# django-social-auth app not working under virtualenv

Tags: django, django-templates

I shifted my django project to a virtualenv. I installed [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/) library using pip. I copied the same files that were working outside virtualenv to the new environment, but I am getting a

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'begin' with arguments '(u'facebook',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I am able to import social_auth library in the django shell and social_auth is included in INSTALLED_APPS and its urls are present in the urls.py file.

What mistake can I be making ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are installing django-social-auth with pip, then all socialauth urls must contain the prefix "socialauth_" . The issue is [discussed on github](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/issues/115).