# NoReverseMatch error with socialauth in Django

Tags: python, django, socialauth

I have been struggling to implement facebook authentication with [socialauth](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on a Django project. I keep getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /mysite/test
Reverse for 'socialauth_begin' with arguments '(u'facebook',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/test
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'socialauth_begin' with arguments '(u'facebook',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I believe I have configured socialauth correctly [(this guide helped)](http://c2journal.com/2013/01/24/social-logins-with-django/), but I do not know where the error could be coming from.

This line in my template test.html is giving me issues:

```
<a href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with Facebook</a>
```

I have looked many places online and could not find a reasonable solution.

Comment: Try it without quotes around `socialauth_begin`: `{% url socialauth_begin "facebook" %}`

Comment: I have tried that. It appears this issue has cropped up before with older versions of Django. You can see I'm running 1.5.1 which means that the quotes are necessary

Comment: Check, have you included social_auth urls in your `urls.py` file: `url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),`, as it written in step 4 from guide you've mentioned. And also, have you set in settings.py facebook params: `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` and `FACEBOOK_API_SECRET`

Comment: Yes, I've already done both.

Comment: I used {% url 'socialauth_begin' "facebook" %} and this works for me running 1.5.1

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting the same error.
I wonder where the error could be occurring. It doesn't seem like much of the code I used is flawed since it was a bunch of copy pasta from working code...

Comment: How was it installed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004398/django-social-auth-app-not-working-under-virtualenv

Comment: I used pip under virtualenv, and I use the socialauth_ prefix...

Answer (score 6):

To save someone using the new python-social-auth and django > 1.4

Use this :

```
{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. The issue is the difference between the new python-social-auth urls and the older django-social-auth urls.